# MySQL Bulk Loader - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: mysql, pentaho, kettle, bulkloader, bulk-load

Hi, I am using `MySQL` bulk loader to dump data from Amazon services to a local table on a linux server but every time I execute it fails at the MySQL bulk loader step saying

```
 MySQL Bulk Loader - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

error log says

```
ERROR 17-12 05:46:49,041 - MySQL Bulk Loader - Error in step, asking everyone to stop because of:
ERROR 17-12 05:46:49,041 - MySQL Bulk Loader - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.pentaho.di.core.row.RowMeta.getValueMeta(RowMeta.java:166)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.mysqlbulkloader.MySQLBulkLoader.processRow(MySQLBulkLoader.java:249)
        at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:50)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

INFO  17-12 05:46:49,041 - MySQL Bulk Loader - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=0, U=0, E=1)
INFO  17-12 05:46:49,041 - id1383 - id1383
INFO  17-12 05:46:49,042 - id1383 - id1383
INFO  17-12 05:46:49,042 - Json Input - Finished processing (I=1, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
INFO  17-12 05:46:49,047 - Select values - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
INFO  17-12 05:46:49,208 - Pan - Finished!
INFO  17-12 05:46:49,208 - Pan - Start=2012/12/17 05:46:25.199, Stop=2012/12/17 05:46:49.208
INFO  17-12 05:46:49,208 - Pan - Processing ended after 24 seconds.
```

can anybody help why this array index out of bound error is coming , I have already verified the previous rows coming ,there are plenty of rows and neither of them have a null value

Comment: Are you also sure that the columns line up? Usually this error is the result of either no rows in the stream or a column mismatch.

Comment: yeah i made sure about the column names by adding it automatically but it failed to retrieve the collect correct column name , i put the column name manually , and it works now

Comment: suggest @GordonWorley posts that as an answer so this question can be marked as such.